# Javascript Bookmarklet: How to remove certain text from document.title before copying to clipboard?

Tags: javascript

I am very new here and I have no clue how javascript works, so please excuse me in advance if I do something incorrectly.
I found this javascript code on github which I use as a Chrome bookmarklet.
It does exactly what I want which is copying the document.title.
But when pasting it, it has additional text which I would like to remove.
For example if I go to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ and run the bookmarklet there, the output is "GeeksforGeeks | A computer science portal for geeks"
I would like to have the "| A computer science portal for geeks" removed so it only pastes GeeksforGeeks.

```
    javascript:(function() {
    function copyToClipboard(text) {
if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {
    return clipboardData.setData("Text", text); 

} else if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.textContent = text;
    textarea.style.position = "fixed";
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.select();
    try {
        return document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch (ex) {
        console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
        return false;
    } finally {
        document.body.removeChild(textarea);
            }
        }
    }
    var markdown = document.title;
    copyToClipboard(markdown);
    })();
```

Can you please help me on this?